# Car stops when I try and take off

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, impala, stopping

Why is my 2011 Chevy Impala trying to stop on me when I take of?

The pedal makes a sort of grinding sound when I try to take off and car jerks and stops completely. It's almost like it's trying to stop itself and the pedal isn't doing anything when it happens. I have to let off the gas and hit it again and then it'll go. Very dangerous.

It does it a few times daily at this point on top of the issue of my steering fluid spitting out (the 2 are likely unrelated because the steering fluid issue just started as the braking problem has been going on for years.)
I put on a new pedal throttle sensor but same issue and replaced the hubs as Chevy said it was needed and still same issue.

Comment: What have garages said when you have taken it in? How many times have you had the brakes looked at in the last few years while this has been going on?

Comment: You say the pedal makes a grinding sound, as in the pedal itself, or the mechanism it's connected to makes a grinding sound? Or do you mean there's a grinding noise when you take your foot off the brake and try to accelerate?

Comment: Please edit your question and reduce it to one issue.  You mention at least 3 issues, "grinding sound...jerks and stops", "steering fluid", and "braking problem".  If you need to ask about each of these, please use one question for each.

Comment: Which pedal? There are several.

Comment: @jwh20 - I believe Vanessa is just trying to relate what's going on and not asking three different questions. All three "things" could be related. Please ask questions to ferret out what you need to answer a question without berating the OP.

Comment: The OP clearly states that the power steering fluid is a separate issue, and has asked a separate question about it, I don't see multiple questions here @jwh20.

Comment: I guess I missed the berating part.  Perhaps your definition and mine are not the same.